# Cannot install Equalizer plugin for Rhythmbox

Tags: elementary-os, plugin, ppa, rhythmbox

I downloaded the rhythmbox ppa.

I launched the command :

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer
```

But the equalizer plugin does not appear in the list of plugins in the Preferences menu.

When I try again, the following message appears:

```
Reading status information... Done rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer is already the most recent version (0.4.1-1~zesty). 0 updated, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated.
```

The plugin seems therefore well installed. However, even when relaunching Rhythmbox, I do not see it in the list of plugins.

I'm using Elementary OS 7.1, based on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the rhythmbox ppa.

What's "the rhythmbox ppa"? I don't know elementary OS, but PPAs are a Ubuntu technology, so I assume elementary OS has Ubuntu packages – and thus ships a recent Rhythmbox by itself.

So, this sounds like an unofficial thing - all bets are a bit off on the package quality of these!

> But the equalizer plugin does not appear in the list of plugins in the Preferences menu.

That sounds like a bug, and simply might have slipped by the maintainers of your PPA. Nothing you can really do, unless you want to start debugging rhythmbox and the plugin. It might simply be an installation issue, so the first course of action would be to open a bug with the PPA.

Since Ubuntu, as said, ships rhythmbox by its own, and decidedly does *not* ship the equalizer plugin, it's thoroughly possible the plugin doesn't work with Rhythmbox anymore – the last time anyone [touched its source code](https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins/blob/master/README.md) was 6 years ago, and that was to add GConf2 support (I'm not expecting anyone to follow me there; the thing is that 6 years ago, compatibility with something that was already a decade old at the point was added; the plugin simply can't have  seen much use and thus bugfixes).

So, my honest opinion there is: don't rely on the plugin for equalization. I don't know elementary OS, but Ubuntu ships `easyeffects`, which you can use to subject specific applications (like your rhythmbox, your VLC and your browser, but not your games) to an audio processor – including a rather nice (for me as signal processing guy; love that I can actually configure the subband filters; not that this would be something that I need to deviate from the default):

[image: easyeffects equalizer view, set to 16 bands (come on, that's more than enough)]